# Is there a Bitcoin equivalent to Infura?

Tags: api

I was wondering if there's some service for Bitcoin that is equivalent to

https://infura.io/

All I could find similar so far is blockcypher, but it appears to require fees while infura doesn't seem to require any fees.

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.blockcypher.com/